# Writing to file via fputc vs fwrite array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I am reading bytes that make up a file byte by byte. If I write directly to the file via `fputc` the file outputs correctly. However, if I use an `unsigned char` array and write to the elements of the array, then write the array to a file via `fwrite` I get a jumbled corrupted file instead:

```
FILE *outfp = fopen("my_file.jpg", "w");
unsigned char *outbuf = malloc(filesize);

for (int i = 0; i < filesize; ++i)
{
    unsigned char byte = my_funcion_to_read_byte(i);

    // Works
    fputc(byte, outfp);

    // Fails
    outbuf[i] = byte;
}

// Fails
fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(*outbuf), filesize, outfp);

fclose(outfp);
```

Is there some magic that fputc is doing or am I missing something?

**EDIT**
As people have suggested the code actually works fine. My problem was  passing an array to the function for modification rather than a pointer to the array.

So rather than `my_func(unsigned char *outbuf, ...)`

I needed to do: `my_func(unsigned char **outbuf, ...)` and call it with `my_func(&outbuf)`

I think I jumped the gun to early on this question, sorry.

Comment: What you've shown us looks fine.

Comment: Doesn't the `fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(*outbuf), filesize, outfp);` append the buffer after the loop did all those `fputc`s?

Comment: It's more pseudo code, I would either use fputc or outbuf not both at the same time. I'm just showing the contrast between the two.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you should open the file in binary mode `"wb"`.

Comment: How does `outbuf[i] = byte;` fail?

Comment: Code is having trouble, yet the return values of `fopen()`, `malloc()`, `fputc()` and `fwrite()` are not checked for error return values.  Seems like that would be the first step.  Unclear why code writing to the file with `fputc()` **and** `fwrite()` - certainly an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a jpg file, and if you mean with "jumbled corrupted" the image shown, then maybe that is because you append the buffer to the file after you have written the image already with all your `fputc`s.

I suggest you write the buffer to a separate file to further test it.

Note: you should open the file in binary mode `"wb"`.